# Is $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n(a_n+n+k)}{n+1}$ eventually a non-integer, for all $k$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a positive integer $k$, let $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n(a_n+n+k)}{n+1}, \forall n \geq 1$. The sequence terminates when a term is not an integer. I'd like to ask whether for all $k$, the sequence will always terminate?

Comment: Please rephrase the title, it is very ambiguous

Comment: What have you tried? Starting out, $a_2=1+k/2$ implies $k$ must be even for $a_2$ to be an integer. Trying $k=2$ in following terms, the sequence grows very fast and it seems it will never terminate.

Comment: I have tried brute force to check, but for many values of $k$, the sequences grow so rapidly that I cannot check the condition easily.

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer, but an observation of a possible closed form, which may or may not be useful.

---

If $k$ is not even, the sequence terminates at $n=2$ since $a_2=1+k/2$.

Hence, assume that $k$ is even $k=2m,m\in\mathbb N$ from now on:

$$
a_{n}=\frac{a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}+n+2m-1)}{n},a_1=1.
$$

For $n=1,2,3$ we have $a_n=1,(1+m),(1+m)^2$. For $n\ge4$, we have a closed form:

$$
a_n=(1+m)^2\frac{\prod_{q=4}^{n}P_q(m)}{\prod_{q=4}^{n} q^{2^{n - q}}}
$$

Where $P_q(m)$ are degree $2^{q-3}$ polynomials, whose closed form I haven't found:

```
P_4(m) = 4+4 m+m^2
P_5(m) = 20+20 m+13 m^2+6 m^3+m^4
P_6(m) = 480+480 m+552 m^2+560 m^3+385 m^4+188 m^5+62 m^6+12 m^7+m^8
P_7(m) = 268800+268800 m+462720 m^2+755200 m^3+968304 m^4+1031520 m^5+923760 m^6+695072 m^7+437393 m^8+228248 m^9+97628 m^10+33672 m^11+9126 m^12+1864 m^13+268 m^14+24 m^15+m^16
P_8(m) = 82575360000+82575360000 m+193757184000 m^2+445218816000 m^3+859568947200 m^4+1461969715200 m^5+2225537781760 m^6+3056330956800 m^7+3805161206016 m^8+4307812899840 m^9+4442780243200 m^10+4179035063296 m^11+3587766859744 m^12+2811942207424 m^13+2011414335328 m^14+1311991731008 m^15+779194844129 m^16+420459425712 m^17+205571845944 m^18+90753700816 m^19+36023470076 m^20+12790205744 m^21+4036272008 m^22+1123264464 m^23+272972390 m^24+57212560 m^25+10177544 m^26+1504496 m^27+179548 m^28+16592 m^29+1112 m^30+48 m^31+m^32
P_9(m) = 7671026339020800000000+7671026339020800000000 m+23113532933406720000000 m^2+69358863148646400000000 m^3+181730645536407552000000 m^4+432555324793159680000000 m^5+949326200107853414400000 m^6+1937457161937145036800000 m^7+3698229470022755942400000 m^8+6629458364228047994880000 m^9+11194619325883845967872000 m^10+17849423468477898817536000 m^11+26925814835234794897408000 m^12+38490878951551146550886400 m^13+52216436054882258591416320 m^14+67305716890148955016396800 m^15+82519005618270199022944256 m^16+96317902101878716497920000 m^17+107112591554945344158433280 m^18+113559753558799360762314752 m^19+114835014065179880619982848 m^20+110804339831534161038901248 m^21+102045621542362432535437312 m^22+89716032629778431338921984 m^23+75306149179780436432840192 m^24+60351528507401658860480512 m^25+46176823042397344755454464 m^26+33727709642654821496342528 m^27+23512273651564620608168896 m^28+15639902493256622240854912 m^29+9923387411824565155387584 m^30+6003363164824765445687936 m^31+3461200203000481641804481 m^32+1900684707363531196375392 m^33+993486934890764213127280 m^34+493926415825156880978592 m^35+233372292082453014814648 m^36+104693371859099408241888 m^37+44547322940611223917776 m^38+17957922152221760565280 m^39+6849632573147007030236 m^40+2468535202863979750880 m^41+839245565270792359024 m^42+268693922784075216928 m^43+80854072928946499592 m^44+22818160069793674336 m^45+6024799036325022928 m^46+1484254891811797664 m^47+340134464562300038 m^48+72254882275851808 m^49+14172626844647120 m^50+2555323035617760 m^51+421308814181640 m^52+63138468403360 m^53+8539761673200 m^54+1033682727520 m^55+110835887964 m^56+10395589280 m^57+839395920 m^58+57146208 m^59+3188472 m^60+139936 m^61+4528 m^62+96 m^63+m^64
...
```

---

It looks like $m=1$ will always be an integer ($k=2$ is a counterexample to your question), but I haven't been able to prove this.

Comment: Yes. I find it quite hard (maybe impossible) to find a general closed form solution, not to mention how to prove whether it terminates.

Comment: Those are some pretty big powers of $q$ down there in the denominator. At first glance it seems very unlikely that all the enumerators are divisible by it. Is there some weird conspiracy going on in the enumerator?

Comment: @Vincent It is hard to say. The $m$ values that are integers for all $n\le 30$ are: $1,3,5,8,13,14,\dots$ but this does not necessarily mean any of them will not terminate. The $m=15$ terminates at $n=29$ for example.  Specially for $m=1$, I've checked terms $n\le 38$, and they all are integers. The $a_{38}$ had over five billion digits ($5,577,665,364$ digits).